# Joomla!2.5 not executing SQL files upon install/update

Tags: joomla2.5

My SQL files aren't being executed when I install or update a new component. Initially I found it weird that my workmate needed to execute his SQL files directly into PHPMyAdmin, but isn't Joomla! supposed to automatically run the files?

Here's how I set up my XML:

*ReforcoDigital.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="2.5.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
<name>Reforco Digital</name>
<author>Rodrigo Pereira</author>
<creationDate>14/05/2013</creationDate>
<copyright>Copyright</copyright>
<license>Licença</license>
<authorEmail>rodrigo-c-pereira@hotmail.com</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>http://www.site.com</authorUrl>
<version>0.1</version>
<description>Sistema de Reforço Digital</description>

<install>
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>

<update>
    <schemas>
        <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates/mysql</schemapath>
    </schemas>
</update>

<files folder="site">
    <folder>language</folder>
    <folder>models</folder>
    <folder>views</folder>
    <filename>reforcodigital.php</filename>
    <filename>controller.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
</files>

<administration>
    <menu>Reforco Digital</menu>
    <files folder="admin">
        <folder>sql</folder>
        <folder>views</folder>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
        <filename>reforcodigital.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</administration>
</extension>
```

Folder *admin/sql* has the *install.mysql.utf8.sql* file, and *admin/sql/updates/mysql* has the file *0.1.sql*; both have the very same SQL code. What am I possibly missing here?

Comment: Having exactly the same problem.  install and uninstall sql run just fine - but not update.  The code you posted (same that I'm using) is exactly as the documentation describes it (and the examples show)

Answer (score 0):

I commented earlier that I was having the same problem as you, but I'm not.  Mine is a completely different problem that I'll describe after I explain what's happening with your file.

So, your sql folder resides within your admin component folder (this is normal), but your install/uninstall sql XML entries don't describe this.  So, I believe that if you make this change, you'll find it working as expected:

```
<install>
    <sql folder="admin">
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>
```

My problem is that the update section will only execute a schema update when a schema exists in the #__schema table - and install.sql isn't executed on update.  So if you're upgrading your extension and adding a table to it, you can't really rely on the XML installer to create your new table unless your extension already had tables before the update.

I'm going with an install.php file to search for and create the table if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that I was updating my component with a *0.1.sql* over and over was the problem. Changed the filename to *0.2.sql* and it did the job.

My understanding is that Joomla! will look for the update files in alphabetical order, and judge if that version has been used or not; correct me if that's wrong. Since there was a higher version than *0.1*, it did the job.

Comment: did you also change the version number to the latest in your_module.xml file?